# pasar variables o valores entre funciones de javascript

Tags: javascript, funciones, variables

espero alguien pueda ayudarme dándome un consejo o una manera en solucionar el problema de pasar una variable entre funciones en javascript. he usado el return para que la función obtenga el valor y después ocupar toda la función pero no me a funcionado.
lo que quiero es que a partir de un IF haga una multiplicación y ese resultado guardarlo para pasarlo a la función de arriba y ya con eso poder realizar una suma de ese resultado con otros valores que tengo.
Gracias por su ayuda y leer mi publicación.

```
function sumadeWatts() {
    var a =+ document.getElementById("Select1id").selectedOptions[0].getAttribute("data-value2");
    var b =+ document.getElementById("Select2id").selectedOptions[0].getAttribute("data-value2");

    document.getElementById("resultWattsTotales").innerHTML = a + b + cantModulosGB();
}

function cantModulosGB() {
    console.log(Select4id.value)  
    console.log(Select4_2id.value)
    console.log('Select4id data-value2 ' + Select4id.selectedOptions[0].getAttribute("data-value2"))

    if (Select4id.value=="DDR3" && Select4_2id.value==0) {
        var suma = 0*0;
        return suma;
        console.log(suma);
    }

    if (Select4id.value=="DDR3" && Select4_2id.value==1) {
        var suma = 2*1;
        return suma;
        console.log(suma);
    }

    if (Select4id.value=="DDR3" && Select4_2id.value==2) {
        var suma = 2*2;
        return suma;
        console.log(suma);
    }

    if (Select4id.value=="DDR4" && Select4_2id.value==0) {
        var suma = 0*0;
        return suma;
        console.log(suma);
    }

    if (Select4id.value=="DDR4" && Select4_2id.value==1) {
        var suma = 3*1;
        return suma;
        console.log(suma);
    }

    if (Select4id.value=="DDR4" && Select4_2id.value==2) {
        var suma = 3*2;
        return suma;
        console.log(suma);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No hace falta que definas una variable y la retornes, si solo quieres retornar el resultado de una multiplicación **eso debes de hacer:** `return a * b`

Otra cosa que creo que es motivo de observación es que, en los condicionales de la función `cantModulosGB()` no unes los `if` con `else if`. A menos que quieras que la función de retorne los valores tomando en cuenta todas la validaciones, puedes usar una estructura `if-else if`, de esta manera apenas se cumpla una condición no se valoraran las otras.

Dicho esto te dejo un ejemplo que cumple lo que deseas (que retorne un valor dependiendo del condicional).

```
if (Select4id.value == "DDR3" && Select4_2id.value == 1) {
    console.log(2 * 1);
    return 2 * 1;
}
```

Espero haberte ayudado, saludos.

Comment: muchas gracias @gabrielcoronel me ayudo mucho tu respuesta y agradezco que tomaras el tiempo de corregir el código y mencionarme sobre los if, no recordaba eso.